# Issues with jquery clone method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function() {
            var driverUrl = ctx+"/transporter/drivers/free";
            var vehicleUrl = ctx+"/transporter/vehicles/free";

            var driverSelectBox = $("<select class=\"form-control input-lg required\">")
            .append("<option selected=\"true\">Select Driver</option>");
            $.getJSON(
                    driverUrl,
                    function(driverIds) {
                        $.each(driverIds, function(driver_index, driverId) {
                            driverSelectBox.append("<option value=\""+driverId+"\">"+driverId+"</option>");
                        });

                    });
            driverSelectBox.append("</select>");


            var vehicleSelectBox = $("<select class=\"form-control input-lg required\">")
            .append("<option selected=\"true\">Select Vehicle</option>");
            $.getJSON(
                    vehicleUrl,
                    function(vehicleIds) {
                        $.each(vehicleIds, function(vehicle_index, vehicleId) {
                            vehicleSelectBox.append("<option value=\""+vehicleId+"\">"+vehicleId+"</option>");
                        });

                    });
            vehicleSelectBox.append("</select>");


            console.log(driverSelectBox);
            console.log(vehicleSelectBox);


            $('ul#drivernvehicle').empty();
            var i = $('#noOfVehicle').val();
            var items = [];
            for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                var list_item = $("<li>")
                .append(driverSelectBox.clone())
                .append(vehicleSelectBox.clone())
                .append("</li>");
                items.push(list_item);
            }
            console.log(items);
            $('ul#drivernvehicle').append( items);
        });
```

here select boxes are being populated properly. I can check from console.log(). but inside the last for loop when i am creating list elements and populating a list item by cloning select boxes. Then the array of "items" where i am pushing elements that items array is notbeing populated by the option values. can't reciprocate the issue. the problem is inner elements of two select boxes are not being cloned. why so .is it because of asynchronus i/o. that loop is being executed before the data comes from ajax call.

Comment: You do not append a closing tag `.append("</li>");` That is wrong. You do it in a bunch of places.

Comment: If it's an issue with timing like you suggested, what about making it clone after the ajax call completes?  Like do the cloning in the success callback of getJSON.

Comment: @epascarello not sure what you are saying. you want me not to include the closing tags for elemnts like <li> and <select>.

Comment: @Prabir You are NOT building a string when you append a new element! If you want the clsoing tag, it should be when you create the element. `var list_item = $("<li>")` should be `var list_item = $("<li></li>")` or `var list_item = $("<li/>")`

Comment: @epascarello is it really a problem. because when I do it in jsfiddle it is working just fine. you can check  http://jsfiddle.net/prmall/aqy827kj/ .

Comment: Yes it is a problem since it is not correct.

Comment: @dustmouse you are correct I just move the clone part after completion of  json request and now it is happening. thanks :)